# Is Spectreman's human form an illusion, or an actual transformation?

Tags: spectreman

In the 1970s tokatsu series, **Spectreman,** the titular hero is a "super cyborg agent" sent by the advanced satellite planetoid, Nebula 7, to protect the earth from the evil machinations of the brilliant alien super simian, Dr. Gori.

Much like his tokatsu predecessor, Ultraman, Spectreman was sent to this planet to protect it, and to do so must blend into the populace. To do so, he has the ability to blend in with humans. *Unlike* an Ultra being,though, Spectreman's powers are not energy based,or voluntary; while he has no human "host" that merges with and needs a particular trinket to activate his powers, he *does* have to "Request permission to transform" from Nebula 7.
The beings on the planetoid will then send a beam of energy down to energize him, initiating the change into his cyborg form. They could also send back up weaponry if he requested.

Considering that his central form is bio-mechanical, though, I was wondering if anyone knew if his human form was some type of holographic projection, or it he actually "morphs" from a a flesh and blood body to a fully cyborg one, if it was a type of "Consciousness transfer", if he's more like Vision where he essentially "re-formats" his appearance but is *still* purely machine, or if there was some other explanation.

The reason I ask is because in at least 2 episodes, when Spectreman transformed back into his "human form" of Joji "George" Gamo, he showed signs of physical injury conducive with the battle which had just taken place.

An obscure show, I know, but it always bugged me as a kid how a "machine" could be so hurt.